# magento instance do not work

Tags: magento, instance, odoo

I have ready installed the magento integration-extension and in the configuration of the instance I have entered the URL of magento- site as well as user and password for the API.

The Magento OpenERP server and the server are separate domains.

When test connection I get the following error message "Incorrect API Settings!"

it would be very happy to help me

Answer (score 0):

I think your are using wrong address

you need to use like this "http://www.magento_xyz.com"
then correct password and correct username

bcz incorrect API that mean you enter something  wrong
so please provide us more details 
so we will help you out

Comment: the url of magento-site ist worado.com and i've used. the password and username are those where i taked in magento soap/xml-user  if posible we can use the skype (myskauer)

Comment: paste your traceback here, 
can you tell me which connector are you using

Comment: the connector https://github.com/openlabs/magento_integration.git

it is gone than I am., a "Default UOM" as "kg" and "magento root categorie" "1000." at 1, I had the error entries Dopelt

I am currently working with wolgenden item "Import categorie" under Site menu and I get a error